# How to convert png to draw.io xml

Tags: xml, image-conversion

I would like to convert an existing png to the [draw.io xml format](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000052874-how-to-create-and-edit-shapes-) bit don't know how to do nor do I know if this is even possible. As an example, the following image

[image]

.. would be described as this:

```
<shape aspect="variable" h="54.74" name="Exchange Server" strokewidth="inherit" w="57.0">
  <connections/>
  <foreground>
    <fillstroke/>
    <strokecolor color="none"/>
    <fillcolor color="#2372ba"/>
    <path>
      <move x="52.49" y="11.33"/>
      <curve x1="52.42" x2="52.45" x3="52.47" y1="11.27" y2="11.23" y3="11.2"/>
      <line x="53.1" y="10.58"/>
      <curve x1="53.13" x2="53.17" x3="53.17" y1="10.55" y2="10.5" y3="10.4"/>
      <line x="53.17" y="8.49"/>
      <curve x1="53.17" x2="53.08" x3="53.02" y1="8.4" y2="8.33" y3="8.33"/>
      <line x="51.57" y="8.33"/>
      <curve x1="51.49" x2="51.34" x3="51.28" y1="8.33" y2="8.35" y3="8.41"/>
      <line x="48.29" y="11.48"/>
      <curve x1="48.24" x2="48.19" x3="48.14" y1="11.52" y2="11.52" y3="11.48"/>
      <curve x1="48.04" x2="47.95" x3="47.92" y1="11.41" y2="11.32" y3="11.18"/>
      <curve x1="48.51" x2="49.75" x3="50.98" y1="10.04" y2="8.32" y3="6.95"/>
      <curve x1="51.1" x2="51.24" x3="51.38" y1="6.83" y2="6.75" y3="6.75"/>
      <line x="54.41" y="6.75"/>
      <curve x1="54.66" x2="54.74" x3="54.74" y1="6.75" y2="6.98" y3="7.15"/>
      <line x="54.74" y="10.28"/>
      <curve x1="54.75" x2="54.7" x3="54.62" y1="10.44" y2="10.55" y3="10.63"/>
      <line x="53.48" y="11.84"/>
      <curve x1="53.41" x2="53.33" x3="53.24" y1="11.9" y2="11.9" y3="11.85"/>
      <close/>
      <move x="50.93" y="16.29"/>
      <curve x1="50.99" x2="51.05" x3="51.11" y1="16.35" y2="16.35" y3="16.35"/>
      <line x="53.01" y="16.35"/>
      <curve x1="53.07" x2="53.17" x3="53.17" y1="16.35" y2="16.3" y3="16.21"/>
      <line x="53.17" y="14.73"/>
      <curve x1="53.17" x2="53.17" x3="53.1" y1="14.64" y2="14.56" y3="14.49"/>
      <line x="50.02" y="11.48"/>
      <curve x1="49.99" x2="49.99" x3="50.02" y1="11.43" y2="11.38" y3="11.33"/>
      <curve x1="50.11" x2="50.2" x3="50.31" y1="11.24" y2="11.14" y3="11.1"/>
      <curve x1="51.82" x2="54.01" x3="54.53" y1="11.83" y2="13.64" y3="14.16"/>
      <curve x1="54.65" x2="54.73" x3="54.75" y1="14.29" y2="14.43" y3="14.59"/>
      <line x="54.75" y="17.6"/>
      <curve x1="54.75" x2="54.53" x3="54.38" y1="17.91" y2="18.0" y3="18.0"/>
      <line x="51.2" y="18.0"/>
      <curve x1="51.08" x2="50.97" x3="50.81" y1="18.0" y2="17.97" y3="17.81"/>
      <line x="49.64" y="16.73"/>
      <curve x1="49.61" x2="49.6" x3="49.64" y1="16.65" y2="16.58" y3="16.5"/>
      <curve x1="49.82" x2="50.09" x3="50.24" y1="16.25" y2="15.84" y3="15.68"/>
      <close/>
      <move x="45.75" y="19.13"/>
      <line x="55.88" y="19.13"/>
      <line x="55.88" y="5.63"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="5.63"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="6.75"/>
      <line x="47.0" y="6.75"/>
      <curve x1="47.16" x2="47.32" x3="47.46" y1="6.75" y2="6.77" y3="6.83"/>
      <line x="48.68" y="7.96"/>
      <curve x1="48.72" x2="48.75" x3="48.68" y1="8.01" y2="8.07" y3="8.18"/>
      <line x="48.12" y="8.96"/>
      <curve x1="48.09" x2="48.06" x3="48.03" y1="8.99" y2="8.99" y3="8.96"/>
      <line x="47.32" y="8.32"/>
      <curve x1="47.27" x2="47.21" x3="47.12" y1="8.28" y2="8.25" y3="8.25"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="8.25"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="10.8"/>
      <curve x1="46.58" x2="47.4" x3="48.23" y1="11.64" y2="12.42" y3="13.2"/>
      <curve x1="48.26" x2="48.27" x3="48.23" y1="13.25" y2="13.3" y3="13.35"/>
      <curve x1="48.14" x2="48.09" x3="47.92" y1="13.43" y2="13.52" y3="13.58"/>
      <curve x1="47.18" x2="46.46" x3="45.75" y1="13.18" y2="12.7" y3="12.23"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="16.43"/>
      <line x="46.74" y="16.43"/>
      <curve x1="46.83" x2="46.91" x3="46.98" y1="16.42" y2="16.4" y3="16.32"/>
      <line x="49.95" y="13.28"/>
      <curve x1="49.99" x2="50.04" x3="50.1" y1="13.25" y2="13.24" y3="13.28"/>
      <curve x1="50.2" x2="50.29" x3="50.32" y1="13.36" y2="13.45" y3="13.54"/>
      <curve x1="49.65" x2="47.68" x3="47.23" y1="14.97" y2="17.46" y3="17.83"/>
      <curve x1="47.13" x2="47.02" x3="46.85" y1="17.92" y2="18.0" y3="18.0"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="18.0"/>
      <close/>
      <move x="36.44" y="16.95"/>
      <line x="40.87" y="17.33"/>
      <line x="40.87" y="15.46"/>
      <line x="38.01" y="15.3"/>
      <line x="38.01" y="13.12"/>
      <line x="40.5" y="13.21"/>
      <line x="40.5" y="11.41"/>
      <line x="38.01" y="11.41"/>
      <line x="38.01" y="9.23"/>
      <line x="40.5" y="9.16"/>
      <line x="40.5" y="7.36"/>
      <line x="36.44" y="7.66"/>
      <close/>
      <move x="31.5" y="21.75"/>
      <line x="31.5" y="2.25"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="0.0"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="4.5"/>
      <line x="56.28" y="4.5"/>
      <curve x1="56.72" x2="57.0" x3="57.0" y1="4.5" y2="4.84" y3="5.21"/>
      <line x="57.0" y="19.49"/>
      <curve x1="57.0" x2="56.69" x3="56.26" y1="19.95" y2="20.25" y3="20.25"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="20.25"/>
      <line x="45.75" y="24.0"/>
      <close/>
    </path>
    <fill/>
  </foreground>
</shape>
```

**Do you know if there is a tool/way to do this?** I've checked the draw.io page as well googled but didn't found any solution yet.

Comment: You probably need to convert it to a vector graphic. You could also use File -> Embed to include a graphic directly.

Comment: Does draw.io support importing other vector formats instead, such as SVG or PDF?

Comment: Yes it does support these formats